# Tools or methods to make LuaJIT ffi definitions easier

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

### Problem

Using LuaJIT's ffi.cdef it's possible to define a C function which is exported so it's callable through Lua.

The problem is that in the headers and in the msdn definitions all of the functions use microsoft typedefs so they basically have to be totally re-written.

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  DWORD th32ProcessID
);
```

*rewritten as:*

```
void* CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( uint32_t dwFlags, uint32_t th32ProcessID )
```

For a few thousand APIs, this becomes very time consuming - and there are so many thousand typedefs in WinAPI that it would be impractical to just copy them from the header.

Does anybody have a faster way of doing this, or a tool that will generate the definitions in the proper format?

Comment: You do realize you can do `typedef uint32_t DWORD` in the FFI, right? Also you could download a pre-existing OS libraries binding from http://wiki.luajit.org/FFI-Bindings#Core-OS-Libraries

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Of course I realize you can typedef, but if you use a lot of windows api you'll notice that it's pretty rare to see just DWORD in the args passeds, with many functions using their own types for that single function.  I manually wrote out about 25 functions and even doing typedefs for them would have required over 30 typedefs for each of the unique types they decided to use. (all of which are basically just uint32_t or uint32_t *)

Comment: (Also iirc `HANDLE` is `void*`, not `uint32_t`)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo void* is uint32_t in 32-bit but you're right.  I just had written that becasue I'm new to using ffi and wasn't sure if void* would work.  I updated the question appropriately though as it seems to work.

Comment: About using libraries that just have it pre-calculated: that still doesn't really help since I would like to be able to do this for anything.  If I don't get any answers I'll just write a tool that analyzes the headers and defines everything required on its own by reading ffi.C occurances in the Lua file.  Because in theory this should be simple automate; ideally a tool would just read the called C api's from the Lua file, analyze the headers and reduce the types, and spit out the required ffi.cdef string.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, it might be worth digging through lua and luajit's mailing-list. I'd be surprised if someone else hasn't ran into this annoyance before in the course of luajit's lifetime and not tried to address it in someway.

Comment: I've already created the tool that does what I describe, took a few hours. I'll stick it on here at some point

Comment: i think instead of rewriting the cdefs your tool should just collect the required typedefs so you have one lua file you just use everywhere (using e.g. `ffi.cdef(require "windows_typedefs")`), because then you can just update your api cdefs without rewriting everything later